# Stripe Connect Custom Account Verification In Test Mode

Tags: stripe-payments

I was testing Stripe APIs for Connect custom accounts, but for some reason, I keep getting pending verification. I tried to follow docs step by step, and I used testing tokens for account onboarding, created Person object, and uploaded testing files that need to be verified on the dashboard. Without verification, I cannot test payouts. I must have missed extra steps, but I was not able to figure it out. Does anyone know how to make it verified for testing?

I have one more question to make sure that I am not misunderstanding the custom account. Can the platform make a custom account have a direct charge instead of a destination charge? And if possible, is liability for returns and disputes still on platform?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the account's [requirements.currently_due](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-requirements-currently_due) hash, it tells you what information are needed to keep the account enabled. You should also use [Connect Onboarding](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/connect-onboarding) to collect the necessary info.

Technically you can create Direct Charge on custom connect accounts. However, it's not recommended. Because:

1. There's no Dashboard for custom account to address disputes
2. There's no Dashboard for custom account to set Radar rules
3. Refunds for Direct Charges on connected account will results in negative balance, which platform needs to cover

Comment: Thank you for you answer!! Is it possible to integrate a section that custom account address dispute on their own by using stripe api?

Comment: Sure you can respond to dispute using the API. Please find more details here  https://stripe.com/docs/disputes/api